# Cygwin "забыл" команды

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin

Может ли Cygwin "забыть" команды, которые при прошлом сеансе работы были доступны? Вчера, скажем, "научил" его делать `ndk-build.cmd`, и успешно с этим работал. Сегодня он будто обнулился! Все пути (вида `$ANDROID_NDK`) помнит, а команды - нет. Есть версии, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Может если bash потерял файл .bash_history . В этом фале хранится история команд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё решилось запуском с правами администратора.